# POST trava o script e não executa o código após submit do formulário

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou com um problema em mãos. Possuo um formulário de cartão de crédito, onde o cliente irá preencher os dados e ser submetido a avaliação do banco. Porém, ele deveria executar algumas operações **antes** de chegar na função que irá enviar seus dados para o gateway de pagamento.
Irei exemplificar um passo a passo do que deveria estar acontecendo:

1. Usuário preenche os dados do cartão;
2. Envia o formulário;
3. Recebe a resposta "Aguarde, analisando dados";
4. Usuário recebe a resposta "Pagamento aprovado" ou "Pagamento negado";

Porém o passo 3 não está sendo executado de forma alguma. Eis meu código:

```
$('#credit_card_form').submit(function() {
    $.post($("#credit_card_form").attr('action'), $("#credit_card_form").serialize(), function(data){
        $("#retorno_form").html(data);
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

O POST é tratado aqui:

```
if ($_POST['f'] == 'pay_credit_card') {
    $bandeira_cartao = $_POST['card_brand'];
    $numero_cartao = $_POST['card_number'];
    $vecto_mes = $_POST['card_valid_month'];
    $vecto_ano = $_POST['card_valid_year'];
    $cod_seguranca = $_POST['card_security'];
    $nome_cartao = $_POST['card_name'];

    if ($_POST['card_number'] == '') {
        echo "Preencha o campo X"
        return false;
    }

    // d_none = display: none;
    echo "<script>$('#aviso_carregando_cartao').removeClass('d_none'); $('#div_formulario_cartao').addClass('d_none');</script>";
    $retorno_pagamento = CS_MundiPagg($bandeira_cartao, $numero_cartao, $vecto_mes, $vecto_ano, $cod_seguranca, $nome_cartao);
    if ($retorno_pagamento == 'Captured') {     
        echo "<script>$('#sucesso_cartao').removeClass('d_none'); $('#modal-close').addClass('d_none');</script>";
    }
}
```

Acontece que ele já passa pelo "echo" acima de CS_MundiPagg() e vai direto para a resposta, no fim do script. Como se ele "travasse" o script após o usuário submeter o formulário e trouxesse apenas a resposta final (pagamento aprovado ou não).

Já tentei de quase tudo, não estou encontrando uma solução. Há esperança no fim do túnel?

Answer (score 1):

Se passa direto é porque a condicional não retorna verdadeiro.

Além do mais é uma condicional muito fraca, inconsistente e redundante.

É inconsistente pois não valida a entrada. Apenas verifica se é igual a vazio e então interrompe. Isso quer dizer que se o usuário digitar um espaço vazio ou qualquer coisa inválida, a validação deixará passar.

Está também apenas fazendo uma superficial verificação do número do cartão e deixa outros parâmetros sem tratamento. No mínimo deve verificar também o mês, ano e o código.

A redundância está no mal uso de variáveis. Declara e atribui variáveis que sequer são usadas.

```
$bandeira_cartao = $_POST['card_brand'];
$numero_cartao = $_POST['card_number'];
$vecto_mes = $_POST['card_valid_month'];
$vecto_ano = $_POST['card_valid_year'];
$cod_seguranca = $_POST['card_security'];
$nome_cartao = $_POST['card_name'];
```

Em seguida faz:

```
if ($_POST['card_number'] == '') {
```

E em nenhum momento usou nenhuma das variáveis acima.

Verifique com `isset()` se cada um dos parâmetros existe.

Após isso faça as devidas validações para cada um.

Abaixo um exemplo para o número do cartão de crédito:

```
function numbers_only($str, $exception = '')
{
    return preg_replace('#[^0-9'.$exception.']#', '', mb_convert_kana($str, 'n'));
}

$c = 'card_number';
if (isset($_POST[$c])) {
    $numero_cartao = trim($_POST[$c]);

    // Verifica se não está vazio
    if (empty($numero_cartao)) {
        echo 'Número do cartão não pode ser vazio';
        exit;
    }

    // Sanitiza removendo tudo que não for numérico
    // Sanitizar é opcional. Depende da política da sua empresa.
    $s = numbers_only($s);

    // Verifica a qunatidade de caracteres. A anatomia de um cartão é mínimo 12 e máximo 19. Note que esse padrão varia de acordo com a operadora e pode surgir uma nova operadora com padrão que modifique essa regra.
    $s = strlen($numero_cartao);
    if ($s < 12 || $s > 19) {
        echo 'Número do cartão é inválido';
        exit;
    }
}
```

É um exemplo bastante simplório mas é o mínimo que deve ser feito.

Para os outros campos, siga a mesma lógica. Os campos mês e ano verifique a entrada se não é vazia e se é numérica. Após isso verifique se a data é válida.

Uma verificação mínima também no campo nome é sempre bom fazer.

E para poupar requisição ao gateway, pode também detectar pelo número qual a operadora do cartão e assim criar uma regra de validação para o código de segurança pois cada operadora possui um formato. Esse item não é obrigatório. Seria apenas para refinar o sistema e evitar requisições desnecessárias ao gateway.

Na verdade mesmo pode enviar os dados sem fazer tratamento algum pois a API do gateway fará as validações de qualquer forma. Isso é agir de má fé e de certo modo é burrice.

As validações são para evitar requisições desnecessárias, conforme comentado acima e também é importante para a UX (user experience). O usuário se irrita quando espera uma requisição e recebe um erro. Dependendo do caso até desiste da compra.

É mais inteligente tratar os erros, comuns e previstos, evitando requisições que custam tempo e processamento. O ideal é já tratar desses dados com JavaScript e por precaução, SEMPRE deve tratar no backend (PHP).

Comment: Não funciona? Estranho, aqui está funcionando. Pois quando bate no `return false` ele não executa o resto. Tanto é que os dados nem são enviados para o gateway.

Comment: Entendi Daniel, obrigado. Mas me diz porque em sua opinião essa é uma condicional muito fraca, inconsistente e redundante? Ela de certa forma não cumpre o que promete?

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo de como tratar de forma mais consistente.

Comment: Entendi Daniel, obrigado pelas explicações.

Answer (score 0):

Eu recomendo que você passe essa parte do código para javascript/jquery, utilizando o `$.ajax()` no lugar de `$.post()`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $("#credit_card_form").attr('action'),
    data: $("#credit_card_form").serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#aviso_carregando_cartao').removeClass('d_none');
        $('#formulario_cartao').addClass('d_none');
    },
    complete: function(){
        $('#aviso_carregando_cartao').addClass('d_none');
        $('#formulario_cartao').removeClass('d_none');
    },
    success: function(html){
       if(html.success)
       {
         $('#sucesso_cartao').removeClass('d_none');
         $('#modal-close').addClass('d_none');
       }
       else
       {
         $("#retorno_form").html(html.errormsg);
       }
    }
});
```

e seu PHP ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
if ($_POST['f'] == 'pay_credit_card') {
    $bandeira_cartao = $_POST['card_brand'];
    $numero_cartao = $_POST['card_number'];
    $vecto_mes = $_POST['card_valid_month'];
    $vecto_ano = $_POST['card_valid_year'];
    $cod_seguranca = $_POST['card_security'];
    $nome_cartao = $_POST['card_name'];
    $status = ['success' => false, 'errormsg' => ''];

    if ($_POST['card_number'] == '') {
        $status['success'] = false;
        $status['errormsg'] = "Preencha o campo X";
        echo json_encode($status);
        return false;
    }

    $retorno_pagamento = CS_MundiPagg($bandeira_cartao, $numero_cartao, $vecto_mes, $vecto_ano, $cod_seguranca, $nome_cartao);
    if ($retorno_pagamento == 'Captured') {
        $status['success'] = true;
        echo json_encode($status);
    }
}
```

Não testei o código, mas veja se funciona.

Comment: Bom, ele faz todo o processo, mas por exemplo, não retorna o erro na verificação `if ($_POST['card_number'] == '')` e nem executa o CS_MundiPagg().

Comment: Editei a resposta, veja se funcionou.

Comment: Quase lá. Na verdade tive que comentar toda a chave de `complete: function()` pois do modo que estava retirava o #formulario_cartao depois colocava de novo junto com a mensagem de sucesso. Não entendi muito bem a lógica aí. Porém, agora ele não me mostra o erro em `$("#retorno_form").html(html.errormsg);` (caso o usuário por exemplo deixe de preencher o "card_number"). É apenas mostrado a mensagem do `$('#aviso_carregando_cartao').removeClass('d_none');`. Já tentei editar aqui de algumas formas mas não estou tendo êxito.

Comment: Ele não mostra mais o erro após você comentar toda a parte do `complete:`? O complete roda sempre, independente se a requisição ajax foi bem ou mal sucedida. Se você não quer que o #formulario_cartao reapareça depois que a requisição terminar, é só você tirar essa parte do `complete:` `('#formulario_cartao').removeClass('d_none');`